OKTA Users API: Next Link Response Header sent even when no further records are to be displayed
I’m encountering an unexpected behavior while using the Okta User API for pagination. Here’s the scenario:
{{okta_domain}}/api/v1/users?after=&sortBy=profile.firstName&limit=20&search=profile.firstName eq “XYZ”

I’ve set the limit parameter to 20 and sorted the results by profile.firstName.
When exactly 20 users match the query, Okta still returns the next link (rel=next) in the response.

According to my understanding, the next link should only be provided if there are more than 20 users, but in this case, it seems to be present even when there are no additional records beyond the 20.
Is this the Okta User API's intended behavior, or could it be a bug? I’ve reviewed the documentation but couldn’t find any specific mention of this behavior.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into how I can address it, I would greatly appreciate your help.
It works as expected when I remove sortBy or Search from the query.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
